# twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 401 error: Unable to create record: Authenticate

Tags: python, flask, twilio

```
from twilio.rest import Client

@app.route('/send-sms')
def send_sms():
    account_sid = 'ACe667c85add9ee216836746661b519bce'
    auth_token = 'AuthToken'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(
       messaging_service_sid='MG9f95524af96c43614a1c8cf4e71ad734',
       body='Xin chao! Day là phong mach tu gia truyen, lich kham của ban da duoc ghi nhan, hay den dung gio kham da dang ky nhe!!!',
       to='+84968384843'
    )

   print(message.sid)
```

I copied this code on twilio.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('send_sms') }}" class="btn btn-success">Send sms</a>
```

I found no tutorial to get the twilio code to work with python flask. I put the code like this and it got the error:

```
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 401 error: Unable to create record: Authenticate
```

Please help me.

Comment: When the error says "Authenticate" it normally means that there is something wrong with your credentials. Can you double check your Auth Token and make sure it is correct. You can find your Auth Token on your [Twilio console dashboard](https://console.twilio.com).